# Problem in rendering View in React js with Bootstrap 4

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Is there any problem in using bootstrap3 or bootstrap4 in react js. I am new to this , so I want to unserdtand the problem of it

Below is my code that ,I treid for it but it's not taking the deafult height , so i tried to give height of 60% of screen but still it's not work

```
const carouselEffect = (props) =>{
    console.log(props.productArr);
return (

    <div className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style={{height:'60%'}}>
        <ol className="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div className="carousel-inner">
            <div className="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" style={{ height: '60%' }} className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" style={{ height: '60%' }} className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" style={{ height: '60%' }} className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
);

}
export default carouselEffect;
```

Comment: Be aware of `data-ride` JSX does not support dashed properties. Are you using a React-Bootstrap library or you just add the bootstrap CSS to your project?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 , not using React-Bootstrap . How to handle the dash properties . Or what I have to do now .Can you please guide me .

Comment: I highly recommend you to use a *React* - *Bootstrap* library in order to implement Bootstrap in React.

React should handle the state in your components, otherwise you will have to write all the functionality yourself.

If you installed `bootstrap` with npm, or added a minfied version of Bootstrap to your project either using `script` tag or `link` tag, you are bringing JQuery into your project and also all the scripts written for Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

use overflow hidden, and it's not good to give height of `img`. We give only `height: auto; width: 100%` to `img` tag. and use `object-fit: cover` to get correct way of image. According to me, you should use image in background of `div` tag, should not use `img` tag because `object-fit` property does not work in old versions of browsers.